# Python Pandas: Count number of times each unique value appears for multiple columns

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have a DataFrame such as,

```
In [7]: source = pd.DataFrame([['amazon.com', 'correct', 'correct'], ['amazon.com', 'incorrect', 'correct'], ['walmart.com', 'incorrect', 'correct'], ['walmart.com', 'incorrect', 'incorrect']], columns=['domain', 'price', 'product'])

In [8]: source
Out[8]:
        domain      price    product
0   amazon.com    correct    correct
1   amazon.com  incorrect    correct
2  walmart.com  incorrect    correct
3  walmart.com  incorrect  incorrect
```

I would like to count, for each `domain`, the number of times `price == 'correct'` and `price == 'incorrect'`, and the same for `product`. In other words, I'd like to see output like so,

```
        domain      key      value  count
0   amazon.com    price    correct      1
1   amazon.com    price  incorrect      1
2   amazon.com  product    correct      2
3  walmart.com    price  incorrect      2
4  walmart.com  product    correct      1
5  walmart.com  product  incorrect      1
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A nested apply will do it

```
In [24]: source.groupby('domain').apply(lambda x: 
                          x[['price','product']].apply(lambda y: y.value_counts())).fillna(0)

Out[24]: 
                       price  product
domain                               
amazon.com  correct        1        2
            incorrect      1        0
walmart.com correct        0        1
            incorrect      2        1
```

Comment: This is a cleaner solution. `x` is a `DataFrame` containing rows which all have the same domain, and you transform the `price` and `product` columns in `x` into `Series` objects called `y`, one per column, then count number of times each distinct value appears in `y`.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [17]: %paste
    (
      pd.melt(source, id_vars=['domain'], value_vars=['price', 'product'])
      .groupby(['domain', 'variable', 'value'])
      .size()
      .reset_index()
      .rename(columns={'variable': 'key', 0: 'count'})
    )

## -- End pasted text --
Out[17]:
        domain      key      value  count
0   amazon.com    price    correct      1
1   amazon.com    price  incorrect      1
2   amazon.com  product    correct      2
3  walmart.com    price  incorrect      2
4  walmart.com  product    correct      1
5  walmart.com  product  incorrect      1
```

Comment: I would not put the ``output =`` and instead just print the output itself